# SwiftUI - How can I set individual customized toolbars/TopBars for each tabItem in a TabView when navigating from another View?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview, swiftui-navigationstack

**Scenario**:

I have a login screen with a "Enter button", as the picture shown below:
[Login Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6qXp.jpg). The code, in its simplest form, is:

```
NavigationStack{
        // Contains BG and rest of elements
        ZStack{
            Image("LoginBG")
            .resizable()
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            
        VStack {
                Image("")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                    .padding()
 
             NavigationLink(destination: RootTabView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)){
                 
                 Text("Enter")
                 .frame(maxWidth: 200)
                 .bold()
                 
             }
             .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
             .tint(Color(red: 6/100, green: 36/100, blue: 42/100))
     
        } // Vstack
        } // ZStack
}
```

After clicking Enter, it takes me to a TabView, with some Items. Code as follows:

```
TabView {
        
        Profile()
        .tabItem {Label("Profile", systemImage: "person.crop.circle")}
        
        MyEvents()
        .tabItem {Label("My Events", systemImage: "house")}
        
        SearchEvents()
        .tabItem {Label("Search", systemImage: "magnifyingglass")}
        
        Rating()
        .tabItem {Label("Rating", systemImage: "bell")}
        
        Settings()
        .tabItem {Label("Settings", systemImage: "gear")}
        
    }
```

The TabView contains, for example, the Profile view. This view looks like this: [Profile Screen with title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhKDU.png) and the code is like this:

```
NavigationStack{
    VStack {
        Image("ProfileBG")
        .resizable()
        .clipShape(Circle())
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
        .frame(maxWidth: 100,maxHeight: 100)
        .padding()
        .padding()
        .navigationTitle("Profile")
        
        Text("User").bold()
        Text("@AppUser")
        
        HStack{
            VStack {
                Text("Events Created").bold()
                Text("0")
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            
            VStack {
                Text("Events Joined").bold()
                Text("0")
            }
            
            
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 330)
    }
    }
```

**Problem:**

When I navigate from Login View to the TabView, the Profile TabView item shows as follows: [Profile without title bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfk7I.png).

As you can see, the Toolbar (or UINavigationBar in UIKit) is not appearing when I navigate from the Login screen to the TabView.

**Objective:**

I would like to have a customized toolbar with different background colors and titles individually in each `tabItem`

I have tried to set the toolbar is all the possible ways available, but either I cannot change the toolbar title when `navigationBarTitleDisplayMode` is set to`.large`. And `.inline` isn't my preferred one.

I've tried to look for answers in google, stack overflow, but it's not that common.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove `NavigationStack` from the `Profile` because parent view has already NavigationStack. Remove navigation title from the Profile and set RootTabView's Navigation Title dynamically as below:

```
struct RootTabView: View {
    @State private var navigationTitle: String = "Profile"
    @State private var selectedTab = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            Profile()
                .tabItem { Label("Profile", systemImage: "person.crop.circle") }
                .tag(0)

            MyEvents()
                .tabItem { Label("My Events", systemImage: "house") }
                .tag(1)

            SearchEvents()
                .tabItem { Label("Search", systemImage: "magnifyingglass") }
                .tag(2)

            Rating()
                .tabItem { Label("Rating", systemImage: "bell") }
                .tag(3)

            Settings()
                .tabItem { Label("Settings", systemImage: "gear") }
                .tag(4)
        }
        .onChange(of: selectedTab) {
            print(selectedTab)
            switch selectedTab {
                case 0:
                    navigationTitle = "Profile"
                case 1:
                    navigationTitle = "My Events"
                case 2:
                    navigationTitle = "Search Events"
                case 3:
                    navigationTitle = "Rating"
                case 4:
                    navigationTitle = "Settings"
                default:
                    break
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(navigationTitle)
    }
}
```

**Change the NavigationBar appearance by adding below code to your SwiftUI APP:**

```
@main
struct StackOverflowAnsApp: App {
    init() {
        let appearence = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24)
        ]
        appearence.titleTextAttributes = attributes
        appearence.largeTitleTextAttributes = attributes
        appearence.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground

        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearence
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearence
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearence
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:** [image: GIF]

Comment: Thank you!. For some reason, I modified the TabView as you did, and  from Profile I removed the NavigationStack  and the navigationTitle. Now I dont see the navigationTitle in "Profile"

Comment: I modified my answer. Please check if helps.